# Explaining a transformation of a formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given that $(3/4)^k\cdot n=1$ can be rewritten as $n=(4/3)^k$ in terms of $n$. Can someone explain in steps how do we get $n=(4/3)^k$ ?

Thank you

Comment: Multiply by $4^k$, then divide by $3^k$ on both sides. (I.e. multiply by $(\frac 43)^k$ on both sides)

Comment: What you may be missing is that $\left(\frac43\right)^k=\frac{4^k}{3^k}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^k \cdot n = 1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^k =\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\frac{3^k}{4^k}  =\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  \frac{4^k}{3^k}  =n$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^k   =n$$

Comment: So from line 3 to 4, we just flip the fractions!! I didn't know this rule before. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Divide the equation by $(3/4)^k$. You get $n=\frac{1}{(3/4)^k}=(3/4)^{-k}=(\frac{1}{3/4})^k=(4/3)^k$